# cannot connect to database using jdbc

Tags: database, jsp, servlets, authentication, connection

Hi im pretty new to jsp and servlets so im having a problem understanding why i couldnt do a simple query. the code is for a login page where the user servlet queries the data sent by the user then matches it to the database then when it finds a match it returns login==true and there another query is executed to get the employee id number matched along with the username and password

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.sql.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.Driver;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;


public class Login extends HttpServlet {


    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException{
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        try {
            HttpSession session = request.getSession(); 
            Connection conn = null;
            PreparedStatement prepState = null;
            Statement state = null;
            ResultSet result = null;
            boolean login = false;
            String username = request.getParameter("username");
            String password = request.getParameter("password");                 
            String checkLogin = ("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");    

            try{

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/matrix","","");

            prepState = conn.prepareStatement(checkLogin);     
            prepState.setString(1, username);
            prepState.setString(2, password);

            result = prepState.executeQuery();

            login = result.next();

            if(login){
                out.println("login");
                String id = result.getString(1);
                String getUser = ("SELECT empLastName, empFirstName FROM employees WHERE empID = ? ");
                prepState = conn.prepareStatement(getUser);
                prepState.setString(1, id);
                result = prepState.executeQuery();
                String first = result.getString(2);
                String last = result.getString(1);

                                    out.println("<html>");
                                    out.println(first + " " + last);
                                    out.println("</html>");
            }


            }catch(Exception e){      
                out.println("ERROR");
                  e.printStackTrace(System.err);
            }   
        }catch(Exception db){


        } finally {            
            out.close();
        }
    }
```

Here's the error i get

```
INFO: The start() method was called on component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Matrix]] after start() had already been called. The second call will be ignored.
    java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1075)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3566)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3498)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:919)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:4004)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1284)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2312)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2122)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:774)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:49)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:375)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:289)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
        at Login.processRequest(Login.java:57)
        at Login.doPost(Login.java:119)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:394)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:243)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to check your MySQL username and password. MySQL has default user name "root"

Try to change your code into this

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/matrix","root","");
```

It means you connect to MySQL server which in localhost (the same computer), with username "root" and password empty string "" (which is the default)

Answer (score 2):

This class is wrong in so many ways:

1. Empty catch block.  You'll never know if something goes wrong.
2. Open a connection in the servlet rather than using connection pool.
3. Hard wired driver class and connection URL.
4. No credentials used to connect to the database.
5. One class does everything.  Better to have one responsibility per class.
6. Mingling UI (HTML generation) and database access.
7. You don't close result set, statement, or connection.
8. try nested in another try; I'd recommend just one.

I'm getting tired now.

It's not clear to me what the problem is.  Did you get an error?  If yes, could you post the stack trace?  If not, what behavior did you observe?

Comment: +1 for many constructive suggestions in point form.

Comment: yeah i know that the class is wrong in so many ways sorry bout that :P.

Comment: Don't apologize - no need for that.  Everyone was a beginner once.  And this is a place for questions, so that's not a problem.  I'm saying that there are areas where I think your code and your question can both improve.  Help us help you - post a stack trace or something that will help us get to the bottom of your problem faster.